# BBB Palette not displayed on Node-Red on Beaglebone Black Wireless

Tags: node.js, npm, beagleboneblack, node-red

My node-red installation does not display the nodes needed for accessing beaglebone IOs ([node-red-node-beaglebone](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-beaglebone)).

In my opinion error is actually caused because node-red-node-beaglebone loads octalbonescript which needs serialport, and something requests serialPort instead of serialport there.

I already tried the preinstalled, stable and lts nodejs version. Additionally npm@2 and npm@3 for installing the nodes. The .node-red folder was also already deleted by me and the node-red-node-beaglebone packaged got installed in the .node-red/node_modules folder started from scrach.

```
root@beaglebone:/etc# cat debian_version 
8.7
root@beaglebone:~# npm -v
2.15.11
root@beaglebone:~# uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.4.30-ti-r64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 4 21:23:33 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@beaglebone:~# export AUTO_LOAD_CAPE=0     #optional
root@beaglebone:~# node-red-pi
1487183133432 Board Looking for connected device  
15 Feb 19:25:34 - [info] 

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

15 Feb 19:25:34 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.16.2
15 Feb 19:25:34 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.9.5
15 Feb 19:25:34 - [info] Linux 4.4.30-ti-r64 arm LE
15 Feb 19:25:44 - [info] Loading palette nodes
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [warn] [bbb] ReferenceError: serialPort is not defined    +seems to be the problem
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [info] Settings file  : /root/.node-red/settings.js
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [info] User directory : /root/.node-red
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [info] Flows file     : /root/.node-red/flows_beaglebone.json
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [info] Creating new flow file
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [debug] loaded flow revision: 513fd923d68021b8ee98fcb250470340
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [debug] red/runtime/nodes/credentials.load : no user key present
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [debug] red/runtime/nodes/credentials.load : using default key
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [info] Starting flows
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [info] Started flows
15 Feb 19:25:57 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
```

Comment: Stack Overflow really isn't the right place to try and debug this as it is likely to require a back and forth discussion. You should probably post it to the google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will give it a try!